# r - computing statistics for variables passed on to setDT

Tags: r

Is there a way to pass on a variables, for which a statistic needs to be computed, to setDT?

The example below illustrates my issue. Only `A` yields the desired result. As I would like to change `var` into a vector and pass its elements to `setDT` via a loop, `A` is not an option.

I also prefer not using `sqldf`.

```
 col1   <- c('Group 1','Group 1','Group 2','Group 2')
 col2   <- c(0.2,0.3,0.5,0.6)
 col3   <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4) 
 X      <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3)
 var    <- "col2"
 A      <- setDT(X)[, list(nbrObs = .N, average = mean(col2)), by = .(col1)]
 B      <- setDT(X)[, list(nbrObs = .N, average = mean(X[[var]])), by = .(col1)]
 C      <- setDT(X)[, list(nbrObs = .N, average = mean(var)), by = .(col1)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can either pass on the variables by specifying it in `.SDcols` and then apply the function on the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`).  If there are multiple variables, make sure to loop through the `.SD` i.e. `lapply(.SD, mean)`.

```
setDT(X)[, list(nbrObs = .N, average = mean(.SD[[1L]])), by = .(col1), .SDcols= var]
```

---

Or another option would be convert to `symbol` with `as.name` or `as.symbol` and evaluate it (`eval`).

```
setDT(X)[, list(nbrObs = .N, average = mean(eval(as.name(var)))), by = .(col1)]
```

---

Or yet another option is using `get` to return the value.

```
setDT(X)[, list(nbrObs = .N, average = mean(get(var))), by = .(col1)]
```